# PHPMailer not sending emails and not returning error

Tags: php, phpmailer

Is there anything wrong with these configuration files?

***Email.class.php***

```
<?php

    class Email{

        public static function Send($to, $subject, $body){

            if(Config::Email()->Enable != true) return true;

            try{

                $mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
                $mail->Debug = 
                $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                    "ssl" => array(
                        "verify_peer" => false,
                        "verify_peer_name" => false,
                        "allow_self_signed" => true
                    )
                );
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     
                $mail->Host = Config::Email()->Hostname;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = Config::Email()->Encryption;
                $mail->Port = Config::Email()->Port;
                $mail->Username = Config::Email()->Username;
                $mail->Password = Config::Email()->Password;

                $mail->setFrom(Config::Email()->Username, Config::Email()->Name);
                $mail->addReplyTo(Config::Email()->Username, Config::Email()->Name);
                $mail->addAddress($to);

                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->Body = $body;
                //$mail->AltBody = $alt;

                $result = $mail->send();

                if(!$result && Config::Debug()->Email) IO::Dump($mail->ErrorInfo);

                return $result;

            }catch(Exception $e){

                if(Config::Debug()->Email) IO::Dump($e);

                return false;

            }

        }

    }

?>
```

***Config File***

```
;Config

[Email]
    Enabled         =   true
    Hostname        =   "domain.tld"
    Encryption      =   "STARTTLS"
    Port            =   "587"
    Username        =   "admin@domain.tld"
    Password        =   "admin$#@!1"
    Name            =   "Admin"

[Cache]
    Enabled         =   true
    Lifespan        =   3600

[Debug]
    Errors          =   true
    Parser          =   false
    Database        =   false
    Email           =   true
```

My application is not sending emails - however, it is not returning errors either. I am just making sure the configuration options are defined correctly.

Comment: can you check your mail server logs? also set SMTPDebug to (1-4) it has great internal debugging

Answer (score 0):

Your code has basic syntax errors and will not run.

You can’t just make up properties and expect them to do magic things, nor can you make up values for real properties that are not defined and expect them to work.

The `Debug` property does not exist. For debug output, the property you want is `SMTPDebug`, and you probably want to set it to `2`.

The `SMTPSecure` property accepts values of `tls`, `ssl` and `false`. No others.

`Port` is an integer, not a string.

Do not disable certificate verification unless you know *exactly* why you need to. “Because it makes it work” is not an appropriate reason.

You do not need to set a reply-to address if it is the same as your from address.

One or more of these may fix your problem, but we can’t guess any further without more information on the problem, which you can diagnose using the advice in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.